# Find Customer information from Child Component using Event Emitter in Angular

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have two Sibling Component. In One Component I have some customer information, on click of which I am passing the id and some more information to the app component. By finding the id I need to find the complete information of the customer and display it in the sibling component.

Below is the code I am having.

HTML of App Component:

```html
<customer-table [customers]="customers" (setSelectedId)="setSelectedId($event)"></customer-table>
<customer-details [selectedId]="selectedId" [customerDetailsRecords]="customerDetailsRecords"></customer-details>
```

App Component:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Customer Records';
  selectedId = '';

  customers: Customer[] = [{
      id: 'henry-gerard',
      firstName: "Henry",
      lastName: "Gerard",
      age: 21
    },
    {
      id: 'michael-platini',
      firstName: "Michael",
      lastName: "Platini",
      age: 40
    },
    {
      id: 'louis-figo',
      firstName: "Louis",
      lastName: "Figo",
      age: 37
    },
    {
      id: 'cristiana-ronaldinho',
      firstName: "Cristiana",
      lastName: "Ronaldinho",
      age: 15
    },
    {
      id: 'leonardo-messiah',
      firstName: "Leonardo",
      lastName: "Messiah",
      age: 25
    }
  ]

  customerDetailsRecords: CustomerDetail[] = [{
      id: 'henry-gerard',
      city: 'Los Angeles',
      gender: 'Male',
      pin: 3123,
      country: 'USA',
      state: 'CA'
    },
    {
      id: 'michael-platini',
      city: 'Miami',
      gender: 'Male',
      pin: 3176,
      country: 'USA',
      state: 'FL'
    },
    {
      id: 'louis-figo',
      city: 'Seattle',
      gender: 'Male',
      pin: 3176,
      country: 'USA',
      state: 'WA'
    },
    {
      id: 'cristiana-ronaldinho',
      city: 'Denver',
      gender: 'Female',
      pin: 3178,
      country: 'USA',
      state: 'CO'
    },
    {
      id: 'leonardo-messiah',
      city: 'Portland',
      gender: 'Female',
      pin: 3165,
      country: 'USA',
      state: 'OR'
    }
  ];

  setSelectedId(id) {
    //console.log(id);
    this.selectedId = id;
  }
}
```

Component A:

```js
export class CustomerTable implements OnInit {
  @Input() customers: Customer[];
  @Output() setSelectedId: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  sendCustomerId(customer: string) {
    this.setSelectedId.emit(customer);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Component B:

```js
export class CustomerDetails implements OnInit {
  @Input() customerDetailsRecords;
  @Input() selectedId;

  constructor() { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following -

`customer-detail.component.html` -

```html
<h2>Customer Detail</h2>
<div>
    {{customerDetail?.id}}
</div>
```

`customer-detail.component.ts` -

```js
export class CustomerDetailsComponent {

    @Input() customerDetail: CustomerDetail;

    constructor() { }
}
```

`customer-table.component.html` -

```html
<h2>Customer Table</h2>
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers" (click)="sendCustomerId(customer?.id)">
    <p>{{customer.id}}</p>
</div>
```

`customer-table.component.ts` -

```js
export class CustomerTableComponent {

    @Input() customers: Customer[];
    @Output() selected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() { }

    sendCustomerId(id: string) {
        this.selected.emit(id);
    }
}
```

`app.component.html` -

```html
<customer-table [customers]="customers" (selected)="setSelectedId($event)"></customer-table>
<customer-detail [customerDetail]="selectedCustomer"></customer-detail>
```

`app.component.ts` -

```js
export class AppComponent {

    customers: Customer[] = // initialize array of Customer
    customerDetailsRecords: CustomerDetail[] = // initialize array of CustomerDetail
    
    selectedCustomer: CustomerDetail;

    constructor() { }   

    setSelectedId(id) {
        this.selectedCustomer = this.customerDetailsRecords.find(p => p.id == id);
    }
}
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhdmgq)

Comment: @tkamath99 I changed your code in several places. Have tested exactly what code is shown? It is working fine on my end.

Comment: It is finding the ID in the app component, but it is not taking that data to the sibling component. Illustration as A -> Data Passed to App Component -> Data Not passed to B Component

Comment: I have replicated the code in CodeSandbox. Please do have a look 
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-rhodes-9mxdo?file=/src/app/customerDetails/customerDetails.component.ts

Comment: @tkamath99 I have edited the answer. Check again. In `app.coomponent.ts` file change `setSelectedId(id: string)` to `setSelectedId(id)`, and it will work.

Comment: I tried with your solution, but it is not printing certain values like firstname, lastname, age

Comment: @tkamath99 That's because I didn't add those values in the html file. Have you checked the code? I just added the `id` property. You should be able to add them by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on the parent component receive the element you want to show on the sibling component and pass it by binding as you are doing.

To do it what you can do is declaring a variable which holds the value to pass to the B component and on the views bind it to the B component.

When the A component emits the new value assign it to the variable and it should be rendered on the B component.